# Why list index in Django Template it's not in the output?

Tags: django, django-templates

I use this in the template

```
{% for num in '0123456789'|make_list %}
        <li>{{ respuesta.num }}: {{ puntaje.num }}  </li>
```

But then, the page only shows something like this

1. :
2. :

(and the rest goes on like that)
Why it doesn't show the elements from the lists?
If I only use {{num}} it prints the actual nums from the for iteration and if I use {{respuesta}} it shows the hole list.
This happens without triggering any error message or anything else (and yes, there are elements in the list "respuesta" and "puntaje").

Comment: Because that is not how Django templates were supposed to work. The idea is that you can *not* subscript with an arbitrary index. This is done deliberately to prevent people from writing *business logic* in the templates.

Comment: Then I should write each <li> with the specific number index and don't use the for bucle?

Comment: @Matiasib: no, you preprocess data in the view, for example to make a list of 2-tuples.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it doesn't show the elements from the lists?

Because that is not the semantics the developers of Django assigned to it. If you use `{{ x.y }}`, then this means it:

1. perform a dictionary lookup, so `x['y']`;
2. an attribute lookup, so `x.y`; and
3. if *y* is an integer literal, like `{{ x.4 }}`, it will access `x[4]`.

But it will never take the *value* of a variable named `y`, only see `y` as an identifier or int literal.

The idea is that you should business logic in the view, not in the template. If you thus want to combine `respuesta` and `puntaje` with [**`zip(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), and make an iterable of 2-tuples:

```
def my_view(request):
    # …
    context = {
        # …,
        'respuesta_puntaje': zip(respuesta, puntaje)
    }
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

in the template we can then render this with:

```
{% for ri, pi in respuesta_puntaje %}
    <li>{{ ri }}: {{ pi }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```